# Is it possible to open links in a Python (3.10) terminal?

Tags: python, printing, hyperlink

If I had a print() statement, for example:

```
print('https://www.google.com')
```

Is there a way to make a link clickable? And would the same apply for a file path, like this:

```
print('path/to/file')
```

What I need is a way to print a link/path to a terminal and then to be able to open it by clicking on it. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: This depends on the terminal (does it support it or not), it's not python question.

Answer (score 0):

Python itself has nothing to do with this behavior- its functionality provided by your terminal emulator.

However, you can open a link programmatically in the browser within python using the builtin `webbrowser` module, for instance:

```py
from webbrowser import open_new_tab
open_new_tab("https://www.google.com")
```

In some scenarios, this may be sufficient.